# Why we can not use past progressive instead of past simple in this example?

Tags: past-tense, past-simple, past-continuous

In the example below, I saw the writer used "when" at the beginning of the sentence and as I thought that going closer to the animal was the background and then noticing the plastic yoghurt pot happened, I thought we should use past progressive.

Example:

> When Mrs May (was going/went) close to the hedgehog, she noticed that there was a plastic yoghurt pot on the hedgehog's head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either could be correct, depending on what happened, or what the speaker wants to focus on.

With the simple past, it means: first, Mrs. May went close to the hedgehog and stopped, and then *because she had moved closer*, she noticed the yogourt pot.

With the past continuous, it means: while Mrs. May was moving towards the hedgehog, she noticed the yogourt pot. The *context* suggests there's a connection between moving closer and noticing the pot, but the grammar does not. Also, this version of the sentence doesn't indicate whether Mrs. May stopped moving.

In terms of *naturalness*, the simple past sentence wins easily for several reasons:

- With continuous actions, while it's correct to use "when", it's much more common to use "while"
- Because Mrs. May is consistently moving towards the hedgehog, "closer" makes more sense than "close"
- In this context with the continuous, the "go close(r)" is unnatural. "Move towards" is much better.

> When Mrs May **was going** close to the hedgehog, she noticed that there was a plastic yoghurt pot on the hedgehog's head.